# Two onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have `onclick` two times on same button, button for some the second one does not seem to work.
What do i need to do inorder to make both of them work.

```
<button type="submit" style="display:none;" id="done">Ok</button>
```

**1st event**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#done').click(function () {

  });
});
```

**2nd event**

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#done", Done);
});



function Done() {
  $.ajax({

  });
}
```

Comment: Finally bound event would get invoked..!

Comment: the ajax is not doing anything on success or on failure - how do you know it is not working? Have you debugged the network requests?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: **Absolutely not!** The first event is directly connected and the second event is delegated, so unless one calls `stopProgation` both should run.

Comment: @Husman I am using MVC and have set breakpoint in Controller, so onclick it should come at breakpoint, but it is not

Comment: it should work just fine...

Comment: How are you clicking on the button anyway? It is `display: none`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Oh.. i see, i did not know about this before..!

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pntws/1/

Comment: Why are you saying `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` when the value of `data` isn't a string of JSON?

Comment: Guys please ignore the content in ajax,only problem is onclick

Comment: @Quentin I show that button onclick , i have not pasted complete code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah works great in fiddle, but not working in local :(

Comment: @Richa can you share some more context to the problem... like how the element is created etc

Comment: @Richa, is the button added dynamically? Can you post the whole script.

Comment: Works for me here - **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BY4D2/)**. Any console errors in your code?

Comment: @shaunakde It is not calling the url part in ajax.

Comment: Because your url has XYZ, is the path of the URL correct? Check network tab.

Comment: @shaunakde Here i have posted it as XYZ , in my program i have written correct path

Comment: Check the network tab in Chrome, or fiddler for firefox. You can see the ajax request there.

Comment: @shaunakde Got it solved. The problem was i was using post, instead of Get so it was not working. Thanks

Comment: Richa accept any one of the solution as ur answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to debug the issue a little bit. The title of the question indicates that javascript (or jQuery) is not handling the click event. This may not be the case.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#done').click(function () {
        console.log('first')
    });

});

$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#done", Done);
});

function Done() {
    console.log('second')
}

<button type="submit" style="display:block;" id="done">Ok</button>
```

This runs fine, see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pntws/2/), the console in my browser logs both first and second messages. So it looks like both events are firing.

You now need to debug your ajax request or your controller. Try getting a simple file (single string within it) and alerting it. Then you can pinpoint your exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Check the Demo It works](http://jsfiddle.net/BY4D2/1/)

[Check the second demo it shows the defualt case ie when it works without error](http://jsfiddle.net/BY4D2/2/)

***Depending on the status of the request output is shown here the output is rejected hence enters the fail case***

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#show').click(function(){
         $('#done').show();
    });
  $('#done').click(function () {
      alert('called 1st');
    $(this).siblings('.col-lg-11').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $(this).siblings('.col-lg-11').attr('style', 'border:none;');
    $(this).attr('style', 'display:none;');
    $(this).siblings('.edit-link').attr('style', 'display:li;');
    $(this).siblings('.cancel-link').attr('style', 'display:none;');
  });
});
$(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#done", Done);
});



function Done() {
    alert('called 2nd');
    var s="sa";  

var request = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.google.co.in",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function(  ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: "  );

  });

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});    

}
```